# Black screen at boot on an HP Probook 4530s

Tags: 11.04, hp

I see there are lots of questions about black screen after boot, but none of them helped me at all. My conf is HP probook 4530s i5-2401m with some ati radeon graphic card.
After some playing with apache and second "hard" reset (not during any kind of update!), it stopped showing log on screen, and showed black empty screen. 
Now, I can login with ctrl alt f1 entering my username and pw, but since I don't have much experience with ubuntu tbh, just don't know what's the next step, if there is one...

Answer (score 1):

Try putting in startx as a command, press enter and see what it says. If there is an error (Which seemingly there is) post it here.

Comment: okay, here it is..


http://pokit.etf.ba/get/?79226d72281f64b573defeaea8ce7f7b.jpg
and then
http://pokit.etf.ba/get/?20ca64e094c1d94899094bb4cf57ed32.jpg
and it hops in
http://pokit.etf.ba/get/?9f29e154f15e961811ad8ced7601765d.jpg

Comment: Try reinstalling/reconfiguring xorg